# Linked List and manipulation

Tags: python, object, constructor, linked-list, append

I need help constructing a LinkedList with no constructor parameters in python 3.3; resulting in an empty LinkedList object. I want to be able to add and remove elements in the front and in the end of list. So far I can only prepend and add things to the front. I'm a little iffy on how everything else works. Here's what I have so far:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, d, n):
        self.data = d
        self.next = n


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None
        self._size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

    def append(self, item):
        pass

    def prepend(self, item):
        self._head = Node(item, self._head)
        self._size += 1

    def remove_first(self):
        pass

    def remove_last(self):
        pass
```

Does someone have a clue? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well that is pretty easy, why don't you try it by yourself first and see what part is difficult for you to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **deque** object from the collections module in the standard library. Your prepend method is called appendLeft in the deque object.

In an other way, you can modify your LinkedList class with a reference to the last node of the list:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None
        self._tail = None
        self._size = 0

    def append(self, item):
        if self._tail is None:
            self.prepend(item)
        else:
            self._tail.next = Node(item, None)
            self._tail = self._tail.next

    def prepend(self, item):
        if self._head is None:
            self._tail = Node(item, None)
            self._head = self._tail
        else:
            self._head = Node(item, self._head)
        self._size += 1
```

Comment: Hmm, is there a way which I don't need to use the deque object? There is much preference in not using it. Wanting to learn how to make my own linked data structures. :)

Comment: Sure, you need to add a reference to the last node in your LinkedList object.